# In MySQL/SQL is it possible to use parameters as a field/column name?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I'm trying to convert some of my SQL statements to use parameters instead of just appending values, and some of my statements require entering the column that is being used, as well as the value to find.

A few example statements would be...

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_environment = 2;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1 AND user_environment = 2;
```

I would LIKE to be able to something similar to this instead,

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? = ?;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? = ? AND ? = ?;
```

I know how to do this in other languages, however I'm required to write this in ASP Classic, and I'm not very familiar with how parameters actually work in `ADODB.Command`

This is a simplified function that I tried to make...

```
Function GetUser(environment, key, value)
    Dim statement, cmd
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    statement = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE "
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 50, key)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 50, value)
    statement = statement & " ? = ? "

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , environment)
    statement = statement & " AND user_environment = ?"

    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 900
    cmd.CommandText = statement

    Set GetUser = cmd.Execute

    Set cmd = Nothing
End Function
```

I understand that when using parameters normally, it basically stores the value in the format specified by the input type. That being said, to my knowledge, the prepared statement would look something like the following...

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'user_id' = '1' AND user_environment = 2;
```

That statement plugged into sql DOES work, however, when executed, I always get 0 results.

That being said, my question is, is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I pretty much need to be able to send a column name as well as the value to be found to this function, but I need to be able to secure it from sql injections.

Comment: You can't use `?` placeholders for column names.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL ([prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)). But in stored procedure form only, not in a function.

Comment: Remember, the PREPARE, compiles and optimizes the query. If it didnt have the column name or table name it would not be able to compile the query. So NO, not possible as you are trying to do it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Q. is MySQL-tagged.

Comment: @Akina Yes, so what did I miss?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I gave the link. Stored procedure. Prepared statement in it. `CALL my_procedure (?, ?, ?, ?)` in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the clause `WHERE 'user_id' = '1' AND user_environment = 2`

instructs database to return records, where

1. abstract string 'user_id' equals to abstract string '1' (FALSE)
2. user_environment = 2 (can be TRUE, or FALSE depending on data)
3. AND operator requires both conditions be TRUE, which is FALSE because of 1

It can potentially "work" only when there is OR instead of AND, or 'user_id'='user_id'.

There are several options for you to make what you want, and the easiest way is probably 
 to use ASP to prepare right statement, i.e.

```
'statement = statement & " ? = ? " <-- comment this out

if (key="user_id" OR key="column2") then 
   statement = statement & " " & key & " = ? "
else
   Response.Write "Error"
   Response.End
end if
```

so it will work only if key is user_id, or column2.

Another option will be to use other function definition, as

```
Function GetUser(environment, value1, value2, value3)
...
```

where you can again check which value is not null and prepare the required WHERE clause.

One more idea is to use dynamic WHERE clause, i.e. it will work as

```
where 
(user_id=@v1 OR @v1 IS NULL)
and (othercolumn=@v2 OR @v2 IS NULL)
...
```

but this will be overkill and will probably makes no sense if you use adCmdText.